# correlation; lower values better than higher values R

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to calculate the correlation between some vector of investment returns and a matching vector that has a number from 1 to 5 rating the quality of the company. It looks something like this (lets call this data `returnrank`:

```
company  returns  rank
at&t     0.09034  2
verizon  0.23341  1
sprint   0.03021  3
```

How can I make it so that when I calculate `cor(returnrank$returns,returnrank$rank)` it treats lower values as better and higher values as worse in the rank column

(ie: if a stock has high returns and what R would consider a low score (1), I want to see a high positive correlation because I am treating 1 as better than 5).

Comment: Use either negative returns or negative rank for calculating the correlation.

Comment: This question isn't very clear.  What do you mean by `cor` treating certain values as "better" than others?  The `cor` function has no opinion about what's good or bad.  If you're worried about the sign, then either multiply it by -1 or interpret it the way you want to.

Comment: @Gregor thanks, perfect solution. Not sure why this didn't come to me earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want:

```
cor(returnrank$returns, max(returnrank$rank) - returnrank$rank))
```

It may be better to just graph the data since it's unlikely to be a linear relationship given the nature of `rank`

Comment: This only changes the sign of the correlation, so it's easier just to do that directly.